# ¿Cómo elimino los espacios en blanco de mis registros en CSV?

Tags: python

Quiero eliminar los espacios en blanco que hay en mis registros del csv, ya que por ejemplo tengo el campo *delegacion* y contiene : `guadalajara`    y esta `guadalajara`              .

Técnicamente son los mismos campos, pero al agruparlos los toma como distintos por los espacio que hay, me parece.
Este es mi código, debo usar *pandas*:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv",low_memory=False, encoding='latin1', sep=';')
file 
file.groupby(by="Delegacion").mean()
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías usar el método [`strip()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html).

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la funcion str.rstrip() o str.replace, el primero elimina caracteres al final de un String, y el otro puede remplazar lo que tu quieras.

Adjunto codigo de ambos.

rstrip()

```
demo = " Demo  Example  "
demo.rstrip()
" Demo  Example"
```

Tambien tenemos replace()

```
demo = " Demo  Example  "
demo.replace(" ", "")
'DemoExample'
```

Adjunto [link](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-a-string/) donde podrás obtener un poco mas de información.

Comment: te agradezco, me sirvio el str.strip()